# Remove duplicate dicts from list based on uniqueness of keys

Tags: python, python-3.x

My question is somewhat similar to this question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/175079/removing-key-value-pairs-in-list-of-dicts. Essentially, I have a list of dictionaries, and I want to remove duplicates from the list based on the unique combination of two (or more) keys within each dictionary.

Suppose I have the following list of dictionaries:

```
some_list_of_dicts = [
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 2, 'e': 4},
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 5, 'e': 1},
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 7, 'e': 8},
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 9, 'e': 6},
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 2, 'e': 3},
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 3},
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 4, 'd': 2, 'e': 3}
]
```

And let's suppose the combination of `a`, `b`, and `c` have to be unique; any other values can be whatever they want, but the combination of these three must be unique to this list. I would want to take whichever unique combo of `a`, `b`, and `c` came first, keep that, and discard everything else where that combination is the same.

The new list, after running it through some `remove_duplicates` function would look like this:

```
new_list = [
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 2, 'e': 4},
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 2, 'e': 3},
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 3},
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 4, 'd': 2, 'e': 3}
]
```

I've only managed to come up with this:

```
def remove_duplicates(old_list):

    uniqueness_check_list = []
    new_list = []

    for item in old_list:
        # The unique combination is 'a', 'b', and 'c'
        uniqueness_check = "{}{}{}".format(
            item["a"], item["b"], item["c"]
        )

        if uniqueness_check not in uniqueness_check_list:
            new_list.append(item)

        uniqueness_check_list.append(uniqueness_check)

    return new_list
```

But this doesn't feel very Pythonic. It also has the problem that I've hardcoded in the function which keys have to be unique; it would be better if I could specify that as an argument to the function itself, but again, not sure what's the most elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dict comprehension to construct a dict from the list of dicts in the reversed order so that the values of the first of any unique combinations would take precedence. Use `operator.itemgetter` to get the unique keys as a tuple. Reverse again in the end for the original order:

```
from operator import itemgetter
list({itemgetter('a', 'b', 'c')(d): d for d in reversed(some_list_of_dicts)}.values())[::-1]
```

This returns:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 2, 'e': 4},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 2, 'e': 3},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 3},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 4, 'd': 2, 'e': 3}]
```

Comment: I ran a `%timeit` in a Jupyter notebook cell with this result: `12.7 µs ± 352 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)` The `remove_duplicates` function in another answer gave `34.2 µs ± 499 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)`. I was trying to come up with a one-liner and then saw this answer. Nice!

Comment: Agreed! Nice answer @blhsing

Answer (score 1):

With the help of a function to keep track of duplicates, you can use some list comprehension:

```
def remove_duplicates(old_list, cols=('a', 'b', 'c')):
    duplicates = set()

    def is_duplicate(item):
        duplicate = item in duplicates
        duplicates.add(item)
        return duplicate

    return [x for x in old_list if not is_duplicate(tuple([x[col] for col in cols]))]
```

To use:

```
>>> remove_duplicates(some_list_of_dicts)
[
    {'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 1, 'e': 4, 'd': 2}, 
    {'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'e': 3, 'd': 2}, 
    {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 1, 'e': 3, 'd': 2}, 
    {'a': 1, 'c': 4, 'b': 1, 'e': 3, 'd': 2}
]
```

You can also provide different columns to key on:

```
>>> remove_duplicates(some_list_of_dicts, cols=('a', 'd'))
[
    {'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 1, 'e': 4, 'd': 2}, 
    {'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 1, 'e': 1, 'd': 5}, 
    {'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 1, 'e': 8, 'd': 7}, 
    {'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 1, 'e': 6, 'd': 9}
]
```